# Composite Factorization

Tags: code-golf, number, factoring

This is similar to prime factorization, where you find the smallest prime factors of a number (i.e. 8 = 2 x 2 x 2). But this time, you are to return an array/list of the smallest composite factors of any given positive integer `n`. If `n` is prime, simply return an empty list.

**Examples:**

- Prime:

  ```
  n = 2
  Result: []
  ```
- Composite and Positive:

  ```
  n = 4
  Result: [4]

  n = 32
  Result: [4, 8]

  n = 64
  Result: [4, 4, 4]

  n = 96
  Result: [4, 4, 6]
  ```

**Rules:**

- The product of the factors in the list must equal the input
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are banned
- An array/list must be returned or printed (i.e. `[4]`)
- Your program must be able to return the same results for the same numbers seen in the examples above
- The factors in the array/list can be strings so `[4]` and `["4"]` are both equally valid
- A prime number is any positive integer whose only possible factors are itself and 1. 4 returns `[4]` but is not prime since 2 is also a factor.
- A composite number for this challenge any positive integer that has 3 or more factors (including 1) like 4, whose factors are 1, 2, and 4.

**Clarifications:**

- Given a number such as 108, there are some possibilities such as `[9, 12]` or `[4, 27]`. The first integer is to be the smallest composite integer possible (excluding 1 unless mandatory) thus the array returned should be `[4, 27]` since 4 < 9.
- All factors after the first factor need to be as small as possible as well. Take the example of 96. Instead of simply `[4, 24]`, 24 can still be factored down to 4 and 6 thus the solution is `[4, 4, 6]`.

**Winning Criteria:**

Shortest code wins since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: As an important test case you seemed to have missed, I assume the result for `32` is `[4,8]` (the first way I came up with fails that case).

Comment: Also, I think if you made the challenge simply undefined for non-positive integers then the question would have less of "how many characters is `if-then-else` in your language?"

Comment: @walpen Will edit momentarily

Comment: Should maybe add a test case like 42, where first composite factor is less than remaining single-prime factor (which just tripped up my attempt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
Òā¨ÉÅ¡P¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9vc2FiaWX//8OSxIHCqMOJw4XCoVDCpv//MTA4)

Explanation:

```
            # implicit input (example: 72)
Ò           # prime factorization ([2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
 ā          # indices ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  ¨         # drop the last element ([1, 2, 3, 4])
   É        # is odd ([1, 0, 1, 0])
    Å¡      # split on 1s ([[], [2, 2], [2, 3, 3]])
      P     # product ([1, 4, 18])
       ¦    # drop the first element ([4, 18])
            # implicit output
```

Note that this correctly returns `[]` for prime inputs.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
»0Æf×Ṫ$-¦×2/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39ot8HhtrTD0x/uXKWie2jZ4elG@v8Ptz9qWuP@/7@uoY6CgY6CkY6CiY6CGRBbmukoGBpYAAA)

#### How it works

```
»0Æf×Ṫ$-¦×2/  Main link. Argument: n

»0            Take the maximum of n and 0.
              Jelly's prime factorization does weird things for negative numbers.
  Æf          Take the prime factorization of the maximum.
        ¦     Conditional application:
    ×Ṫ$         Pop the last element of the array and and multiply all elements
                of the remaining array with it.
       -        Replace the element at index -1 with the corresponding element in
                the result.
              This effectively multiplies the last two elements of the array.
         ×2/  Multiply the factors in non-overlapping pairs. If the last element
              does not have a partner, leave it unmodified.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell 150

Pretty basic answer but:

```
r n=p n$n-1
p 1 _=[]
p n 1=[n]
p n m
 |n`mod`m==0=p(n`div`m)(m-1)++r m
 |1>0=p n$m-1
i[x,y,z]=[x*y*z]
i(x:y:z)=x*y:i z
i _=[]
c n
 |n>0=i.r$n
 |1>0=[]
```

Works very straightforwardly: find all the prime factors of the input (the `p` function) in a way that produces them sorted ascending, and multiply them by twos (with the exception of multiplying three together if there are an odd number, to handle cases like `32` that prime factor into `[2,2,2,2,2]`. Example usage `c 2880 = [4, 4, 4, 45]`.

*Bonus fun*

As a massively ineffecient prime generator: `primes = filter (> 1) . zipWith (-) [2..] $ map (product . c) [1..]`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6 112

```js
c=n=>{with(a=[]){for(i=k=1;i++<n;)for(;1^n%i;n/=i)push(++k%2?pop()*i:i);k%2||push(pop()*pop());return k<3?[]:a}}

test=k=>{console.log("n = "+k);console.log(c(k))};
test(-1);
test(0);
test(2);
test(4);
test(64);
test(96);
test(32);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>106 104</s> 101 bytes

```hs
c x=2/=sum[1|0<-mod x<$>[1..x]]
(x:r)%n|c x,mod n x<1,d<-div n x,c d=x:g d|1<3=r%n
e%n=e
g n=[4..n]%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#LY4xb4MwEIV3/4onVCRQwIWmQxXhSFWX7h0pA8JOsApny5iEgf9OTdrl9N37nnSnR2ucx4ch78zA360ddNd6fVPIc5BSUkkYgtcGF@NQPZ1hrHKtD8u9110PPUHT0M17UxOsU0NgmAs@2@lHDQPeeMHGNjgBO/sv7xKvJo@yKFLGHlgEFUV/vNd2SCgvUxwOmHpzD2mgCPk5jP8suYIeheiboq3DIl6exTSPdbkWVT4aiSW8W5ecL03DkuXk0pjW0Mt2R8GWmaxyqW/7knWQYjldIdeyOgoXE1MxCcXCFVG/ck5NTNv2Cw)

**Less golfed and explanation:**

```
c x = 2 /= sum[1|0<-map(mod x)[1..x]] -- counts number of divisors of x and returns true for all non-primes

g n = f [4..n] n            -- call f with a list of factor candidates and n

f []    n = []              -- if there are no factor candidates, return the empty list
f (x:r) n                   -- for the factor candidate x ...
    | c x,                  --    check if x is composite
      (d,m) <- divMod n x,  --    set d = n div x and m = n mod x
      m < 1,                --    n is divided by x if m = 0
      c d                   --    check that d is composite or 1
    = x : f (x:r) d         -- if all those checks are true append x to the list and determine the composites for d
    | otherwise = f r n     -- otherwise check the next candidate
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 94 bytes

```
n=>{for(a=[],d=2,l=q=0;n>1;)n%d?d++:(n/=d,q&&(a[l++]=q*d),q=q?0:d);q&&l&&(a[l-1]*=q);return a}
```

Ungolfed:

```
n=>{ //function declaration
  for(
    a=[], //the list
    d=2, //current factor
    l= //next index of the list
    q=0; //stored factor
    n>1; //while n>1
  )
    n%d? //if the factor is not a factor of current n
      d++ //go to next factor
      :( //else
        n/=d, //remove the factor
        q&& //if a factor is stored,
          (a[l++]=q*d), //add multiple of the saved factor and current factor
        q=q?0:d //store factor if it doesn't exist
      ); //end else
   //implicit for loop close 
  q&& //if there is remaining factor
    l&& //if the input is not a prime
      (a[l-1]*=q); //place the factor in the last element in the list
  return a //return the list
} //end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 83 bytes

```perl6
my&f=->\n {my \p=min grep {n%%$_&!is-prime $_|n/$_},2..^n;Inf>p??flat p,f n/p!![n]}
```

Note: uses the `is-prime` builtin

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@3Ui3NVtcuJk@hOrdSIabANjczTyG9KLVAoTpPVVUlXk0xs1i3oCgzN1VBJb4mT18lvlbHSE8vLs/aMy/NrsDePi0nsUShQCdNIU@/QFExOi@29r81V3FipUKahpkmjGVsBGeamcCZlggFhgYWmtb/AQ)

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@3Ui3NVtcuJq86z04jt1IhpsA2NzNPIb0otUChOk9VVSVeTTGzWLegKDM3VUElviZPXyW@VsdITy8uT9PePrpApyZNIU@/IFZRMTovtva/NVdxYqVCmoaZJoxlbARnmpnAmZYIBYYGFprW/wE)